# window.open() not working in phonegap build using new cordova and crosswalk plugin?

Tags: android-webview, phonegap-build, inappbrowser, crosswalk-runtime

I´m experimenting with the new support for crosswalk webview using Phonegap Build
but run into some problem using window.open()

*Info about the new cordova and crosswalk support* 
[http://phonegap.com/blog/2015/06/16/phonegap-updated-on-build/](https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser)

My config.xml

```
    <preference name='phonegap-version' value='cli-5.1.1' />
    <gap:plugin name='org.crosswalk.engine' version='1.3.0' source='pgb' />
    <access origin="*" />
```

I am trying these javascript calls:

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org');  //Loads in the webview
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank');  //Loads in the InAppBrowser
```

*Javascript "syntax" from here:*
https://wiki.apache.org/cordova/InAppBrowser

Result: 
Nothing happens at all..
(It works great when I´m building my project without the new cordova and crosswalk).

**When building in Phonegap build with the new cordova/crosswalk:**

PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows)
cli-5.1.1 (3.8.0 / 4.0.2 / 3.8.1)

**When building without:**

PhoneGap (iOS / Android / Windows)
3.7.0 / 3.7.0 / 3.7.0

(My test device is an Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 running 4.4.4)

Comment: Where is your "white-list"? and your "white-list" plugin?

Comment: The <access origin="*" /> is suppose to be my whitelist. I have tried both with and without. According to this URL, Cordova's default security policy allows access to any site. http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html .Also as mentioned, my "test-app" works fine in default mode (version 3.7.0) Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 0):

@Mikael,
it appears to be true that people only read what they want to read.

I asked, do you have:

1. a white-list
2. the white-list plugin

You said, "yes, I have a white-list". Where is your plugin? Did you read that part?

This is an "official" forum post, not blog, but forum post. Please read.
*Notes for upgrading to cli-5.1.1 on PGB* 
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/notes-for-upgrading-to-cli-5-1-1-on-pgb

Best of Luck,
Jesse

Comment: hm.. I said "<access origin="*" /> is suppose to be my whitelist".. meaning that I dont know if it is complete. I also linked to the source I got that row from and I dont see anything about needing a plugin in that link. That link also says that "Access all domains is the default value for newly created CLI projects". I also..

Comment: ..said that I tried both with and without using a whitelist and none of them worked. Your link also says "IF you're utilizing a whitelist.." does that also mean that if I dont do it then it will fall back on using the default "all allowed"? Anyway, thank you for your link and your reply, I will try this as soon as possible. Hopefully it solves my problem.